# Estimate from above the series: $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(i-j)^2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Estimate from above the series:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(i-j)^2}$$
for $n\in\mathbb N$, $j=1,2,\dots,n$ and $j\neq i$. I'd like to know an estimate dependent by $j$. This question comes from a simple curiosity but I have no idea to solve it. Do anyone have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean a double summation, or estimate for each value of $j$?

Comment: I mean an estimate for each value of $j$.

Comment: **Hint:** $~\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n}_{(i\neq j)}=\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}+\sum_{i=j+1}^n~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the @Lucian idea, the problem can be reduced to the estimation of partial sums:
$$\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1{k^2}.$$
Now,
$$
\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1{k^2}\ge\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1{k(k+1)} =
\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1k - \frac1{k+1} = \frac1n - \frac1{m+1}
.
$$